# SWT cursor text

Tags: java, swt

I need to set the cursor for `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` control in Java using the `Text.setCursor(Cursor cursor);` to a normal "text-select-cursor". The one which is the default, i.e. while hovering this text.

What is the correct `SWT` constant? I have already searched on Google but without finding an example.

Code example for the `SWT.CURSOR_HAND`:

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
Cursor cursor = Display().getCurrent().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND);
text.setCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: I presume you don't actually want to use that cursor on the `Text` widget, as it's already the default. Or do you need to revert a previous change of the cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SWT.CURSOR_IBEAM
```

is the answer.

Some references:

- [I-beam pointer](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/ibeam.htm)
- [SWT constants](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#CURSOR_IBEAM)

---

If you just want to revert the `Cursor` to the default of the `Control`, simply call `Control#setCursor(null)`:

> Sets the receiver's cursor to the cursor specified by the argument, or to the default cursor for that kind of control if the argument is `null`.

[Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setCursor(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Cursor))